# Is there a default limit on concurrency in overpass-api?

Tags: openstreetmap, api, overpass-api

I have setup overpass-api in my local machine (16gb ram,32 core,2399Mhz).
I send 100 threads each with one request like this:

```
(data=[out:json];node(around:10000,13.0894,80.2428)['amenity'];out count;)
```

The time taken is around 18-19 seconds for the last thread to finish, this seems to be very long since, the single query takes only less than 1 sec to finish.

Is there a default limit on concurrency in overpass-api?

Comment: hard drive might be a factor do you have a SSD hard-drive?